# Is it possible to create conditional attribute as DisplayIf?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create an attribute to use with my viewmodel. I want to display different textstrings depending on a third value.

I would like to do something like this...

```
[DisplayIf("IsPropertyValid", true, Name="value 1")]
[DisplayIf("IsPropertyValid", false, Name="value 2")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }

public bool IsPropertyValid { get; set; }
```

Depending on whether my value IsPropertyValid is true or not I want to show one or the other. Ie. When property IspPropertyValid equals true "value 1" will be the displaytext and if not it will be "value 2".

Is this possible with ASPNET.MVC attributes? Or even better... a combinated one like....

```
[DisplayIf("IsPropertyValid", new {"value 1", "value 2"})].
public string MyProperty { get; set; }

public bool IsPropertyValid { get; set; }
```

Then the attribute checks the value of IsPropertyValid and makes sure the value displayed is "value 1" or "value 2".

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how to go about this.

What we'll do is create a simple class called *Person* and display some basic information about them.

A Person has two properties

- Name
- IsActive

The `IsActive` property is a bool value and will be the property used to determine what the user's name is displayed as.

Ultimately what we'll do is apply a new attribute called `DisplayIf` to the Name property. It looks like this:

```
[DisplayIf("IsActive", "This value is true.", "This value is false.")]
```

First, let's create our model. Create a class called **Person** and put it into a **Models** folder.

### Models/Person.cs

```
public class Person
{
    [DisplayIf("IsActive", "This value is true.", "This value is false.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Create a folder called **Attributes** and then put the following class in it:

### Attributes/DisplayIfAttribute.cs

```
public class DisplayIfAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string _propertyName;
    private string _trueValue;
    private string _falseValue;

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get { return _propertyName; }
    }

    public string TrueValue
    {
        get { return _trueValue; }
    }

    public string FalseValue
    {
        get { return _falseValue; }
    }

    public DisplayIfAttribute(string propertyName, string trueValue, string falseValue)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
        _trueValue = trueValue;
        _falseValue = falseValue;
    }
}
```

Let's create a simple controller and action. We'll use the common */Home/Index*.

### Controllers/HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeIndexViewModel viewModel = new HomeIndexViewModel();

        Person male = new Person() { Name = "Bob Smith", IsActive = true };
        Person female = new Person() { Name = "Generic Jane", IsActive = false };

        Person[] persons = {male, female};

        viewModel.Persons = persons;

        return View(viewModel);
    }

}
```

Create a new folder called **ViewModels** and create a **HomeViewModels.cs** class.

### ViewModels/HomeViewModels.cs

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Our **Index** view is very simple.

### Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
@model HomeIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</div>
```

`DisplayForModel` will work when you create this display template:

### Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/HomeIndexViewModel.cshtml

```
@model HomeIndexViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Persons)
```

`DisplayFor` -> Persons will work when you create this display template:

### Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Person.cshtml

```
@model Person

@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if (prop.HasDisplayIfAttribute())
    { 
        <p>@Html.DisplayIfFor(x => prop)</p>
    }
    else
    { 
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(x => prop.Model)</p>
    }
}
```

But what are these methods in this display template? Create a new folder called **Extensions** and add the following classes:

### Extensions/ModelMetaDataExtensions.cs

```
public static class ModelMetaDataExtensions
{
    public static bool HasDisplayIfAttribute(this ModelMetadata data)
    {
        var containerType = data.ContainerType;
        var containerProperties = containerType.GetProperties();
        var thisProperty = containerProperties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == data.PropertyName);
        var propertyAttributes = thisProperty.GetCustomAttributes(false);
        var displayIfAttribute = propertyAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x is DisplayIfAttribute);

        return displayIfAttribute != null;
    }
}
```

### Extensions/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DisplayIfFor<TModel, TProperty>
        (this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        where TProperty : ModelMetadata
    {
        string returnValue = string.Empty;

        var modelMetaData = expression.Compile().Invoke(helper.ViewData.Model);

        var containerType = typeof(TModel);
        var containerProperties = containerType.GetProperties();
        var propertyInfo = containerProperties
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == modelMetaData.PropertyName);
        var attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x is DisplayIfAttribute) as DisplayIfAttribute;
        var conditionalTarget = attribute.PropertyName;

        var conditionalTargetValue = (bool)containerType
            .GetProperty(conditionalTarget).GetValue(helper.ViewData.Model);

        if (conditionalTargetValue)
        {
            returnValue = attribute.TrueValue;
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = attribute.FalseValue;
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(returnValue);
    }
}
```

The final output:

[image: Output]

Comment: It sure can be handled this way. Though it is not the 'simple' solution I was hoping for. I was more hoping for a solution that handled it all inside the attribute, just like you can for a validation attribute, (for example a [RequiredIf("IsActive", true)])